# Matlab BlobAnalysis (for cell counting)

Tags: matlab, count, image-segmentation

I have been researching on how to program image processing for counting objects and I found the following [homepage about Matlab for cell counting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/cell-counting.html)

I am not familiar with Matlab, but found their ideas interesting, so reading this, I see that they are using a **BlobAnalysis Object** to find the centroid of the segmented cells (You can see the image :
[image: Counted cells]

Now, this seem very interesting but I wonder what this operation is doing exactly? (please don't give me the definition written in the docs-"it is finding the *property* in the blobs". How? is it segmenting it? separating it? ) As far as I can see either you separate the cells first (that is the whole point of counting- I am doing this in other program using watersheding) and then finding the centroids is just something added and not so important, OR somehow this blob analysis is doing some interesting segmentation itself that I would like to know.

Anyone familiar with this can give me some pointers or advice here?

Comment: Huh... The link you posted has the code. It erodes, dilates, and binarizes using Otsu. Also if you navigate through the help pages, you can see the algorithm it uses (e.g. I got to here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/blobanalysis.html). Everything is in the docs

Comment: One thing to mention is that your BlobAnalysis Object doesn't actually do the segmentation, it just analyses connected areas in the binarized images.